# How to add .net core dll to an existing .net framework project?

Tags: .net-core, dllimport, .net-framework-version

I have a dll target **.NET core** because of using following library

```
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
```

for creating a UWP App on Windows

Now I would like to import that dll in my currently project which target .net framework in Unity

However add new reference to my .net framework project seem not to work because of incompatibility.

Its possible to convert .net core dll in .net framework ?
I did try to create new **.NET framework** dll and **.NET Standard** for trying target both but .net standard and .net framework do not support

```
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
```

Which possible solution do I have now ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add .Net Core Dll to .Net framework because its not reverse compatible. However you can use a .Net Standard Dll in a .Net Framework project.

Standard is compatible with both Core and Framework.

Comment: Like I mention above. I did try to create new .net standard dll but my dll should have using Windows.Network.Sockets, which its not support in .net standard. So I cant use .net standard. :(